# javascript regex should end with a valid match

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to determine whether the input ends in correct format, I have wrote this regex match again this

```
var inp_values = '<@448746017987231756> 3 <@533932209300832266> 5 <@440684023463804938> 7'

var res = inp_values.match(/<@(\d*)> \d*/g)
console.log(res);
```

> ```
> [ '<@448746017987231756> 3',   '<@533932209300832266> 5',   '<@440684023463804938> 7' ]
> ```

but I want it to return false when value is

```
var inp_values = '<@448746017987231756> 3 <@533932209300832266> 5 <@440684023463804938> 7 @alphatext 5'
```

So I tried this appending $ to the regex

```
 inp_values.match(/<@(\d*)> \d*$/g);
```

but it returns only one value for the first scenario

Comment: It does not match the second string as expected. See [here](https://regex101.com/r/YTVsWI/1)

Comment: I am terribly sorry, I need to extract the matches from inside the string..

let me edit the question

Comment: so you want `<@440684023463804938> 7` to match for both the strings?

Comment: Do you want to _extract_ the @-numbers, or do you want to _validate_ that the string contains only `<@XXX...> XXX..` separated by spaces? You can't do both at the same time.

Comment: oh! thanks Amadan, so I will validate it first and then match it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `RegEx.prototype.test()` function will return `true` if the regex finds 1 or more positive matches or `false` when no results are found.

The `String.prototype.match()` function is looking for a matches in the string and returns an array of results.

```js
var regEx = /<@(\d*)> \d*$/g;

var inp_values = '<@448746017987231756> 3 <@533932209300832266> 5 <@440684023463804938> 7'
console.log("inp_values test return: " + regEx.test(inp_values));
console.log("inp_values match return: " + inp_values.match(regEx));

var inp_values2 = '<@448746017987231756> 3 <@533932209300832266> 5 <@440684023463804938> 7 @alphatext 5'
console.log("inp_values2 test return: " + regEx.test(inp_values2));
console.log("inp_values2 match return: " + inp_values2.match(regEx));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to validate that the string consists of your pattern, you could match it for the first value and then repeat it preceded by a whitespace.

If a single value is also value, you could repeat it 0+ times using a non capturing group `(?: <@(\d*)> \d*)*`.

If it should occur at least 2 times, you could repeat it 1+ times.

```
<@(\d*)> \d*(?: <@(\d*)> \d*)*$
```

See the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/zLZ76B/1)

```js
[
  "<@448746017987231756> 3 <@533932209300832266> 5 <@440684023463804938> 7",
  "<@448746017987231756> 3 <@533932209300832266> 5 <@440684023463804938> 7 @alphatext 5"
].forEach(s => {
  console.log(/<@(\d*)> \d*(?: <@(\d*)> \d*)*$/.test(s) + " => " + s);
});
```